# Lubridate summarise on a nonfixed "monthly" basis

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following data:

```
Customer <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
Invoice <- c(100:134)
Invoice.Date <- c('20200223','20200226','20200301','20200314','20200314','20200401','20200405','20200302','20200604','20201103','20201012','20200710','20200804','20200813','20200912','20201001','20201030','20201031','20201101','20201014','20200915','20200213','20200304','20201003','20200505','20200617','20200520','20201005','20200403','20200303','20200915','20201003','20201101','20201001','20200901')

invoices <- data.frame(Customer, Invoice, Invoice.Date)
```

I know how to get a monthly invoice counts as such

```
invoices %>%
  group_by(month = floor_date(as.Date(as.character(Invoice.Date), "%Y%m%d"), "month")) %>%
  count(Customer, name = "monthly") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = month, values_from = monthly)
```

I would however like to get a count based on "previous monthly period" based on the last invoice date.

So the last column should have 10/24 - 11/23, the one before that 9/24 - 10/23, etc. I have a few slow ideas in mind, is there something faster in lubridate or elsewhere?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Why do the periods break at the 24th of the month?